# Why Dispatch_group_notify works different in different environment?

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

The first situation is that I create a Command Line Tool Application,and run this code.

```
    NSLog(@"Main:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Task1:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Task2:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Finish:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });
```

The log in terminal is

```
    Main:<NSThread: 0x1028033b0>{number = 1, name = main}
    Task2:<NSThread: 0x10040f0f0>{number = 2, name = (null)}
    Task1:<NSThread: 0x1006008d0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
```

If I want to show last log in `queue` and replace the `main queue`

```
     dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Finish:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });
```

with `queue`

```
     dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
        NSLog(@"Finish:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    });
```

The terminal print the last log.But why it can't revoke in Main queue?

When i copy this code to simple iOS Application.All works well:

```
Main:<NSThread: 0x600000070ac0>{number = 1, name = main}
Task2:<NSThread: 0x6000002633c0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
Task1:<NSThread: 0x600000263480>{number = 4, name = (null)}
MainFinish:<NSThread: 0x600000070ac0>{number = 1, name = main}
```

And I try to add  `sleep(1)` over Task1 in 'Command Tool Line', but it seems block the queue and only print log:Task2.... But this all works well in simple iOS Application.

Why lead to these different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uueyV.png)

Unlike other queues that active on created,you should call `dispatch_main()` method to execute blocks submitted to main thread

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFlu.png)

The reason for the same code runs well in iOS Application is that the application start a default runloop which execute the task submitted to the main queue according to a certain rule like UI update notification.

The reference as follow:

[swift-corelibs-libdispatch](https://apple.github.io/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/tutorial/)

[Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2)

Comment: Thanks jimmy, I still have a problem.I'm new to reading the libdispatch recently,I've seen the implementation of dispatch_main().If current thread is main,invoke pthread_exit() to drain the main queue.But how was this code working? I think when the group queue is finish, it submit the block to target queue(Main queue),but the main queue was drained,so the application recreate a clean main queue for this programme? What's you idea?